# Post.php not working?

Tags: wordpress

For some reason, I keep getting this error everytime I try to publish a post. I haven't done anything to move post.php, so I don't know why I would be getting this error.

This site can’t be reached

The webpage at .../wp-admin/post.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Anybody know why this might be happening? I replaced my domain name with ... because it just leads you to the login of my wordpress if you try to follow the link.

Comment: Any recent changes to `wp-config.php`? any recent changes into your database tables? any recent Wordpress updates?

Comment: I have a prompt to update the theme but it says that if I do, I'll lose anything I've done